# NetSuite - Mass Import Duplication Detection

Tags: netsuite

I'm in the process of migrating a large set of custom records into NetSuite. There's already some data and I was wondering how we can manage duplication here apart from manual checks using excel? I know for customers, vendors, partners and contacts NetSuite already offers build in duplication detection when we do data import, but is there something we can create for custom records?

Comment: May be you need to enable Run Server SuiteScript and Trigger Workflows option and run a script before submit to check for duplication and merge them.

Answer (score 1):

Try building a UserEvent script that throws an exception on beforeSave at creation, if the validation has't passed. I haven't tested this, but it could act as a filter when importing.